# Знаки препинания: "Ты мне я тебе"

Tags: пунктуация

В Нацкорпусе встречаются варианты:

1. Ты мне, я тебе.
2. Ты - мне, я - тебе.
3. Ты мне - я тебе.

На все воля автора или есть какие-то объективные критерии?

Answer (score 2):

В предложениях эллиптического вида "**подлежащее + дополнение**" выбор знака **зависит от интонации.** Автор может использовать любой вариант, но при этом нужно понимать, какую интонацию он выбирает.

Варианты 1 и 2 сходны тем, что **перед запятой делается понижение тона** (как в конце предложения), а различаются они паузами, обозначенными тире.

Вариант 3 состоит из двух фраз: ты мнЕ ― я тебЕ (повышение тона ― пауза ― понижение тона), так (делением предложения на две части) обозначается **противопоставление.**

Answer (score 2):

**Все три варианта постановки знаков возможны.**

В первом случае между простыми  предложениями используется перечислительная интонация. *Ты мне, я тебе.* Ставим запятую.

Во втором случае на месте тире при произношении необходимы паузы после подлежащих ТЫ и Я.  *Ты - мне, я - тебе*. Предложение интонационно становится более выразительным.

В третьем случе оформляем предложение как БСП с противительными отношениями между простыми предложениями. Ставим тире на месте отсутствующего противительного союза А. *Ты мне - я тебе.* Пауза увеличивается между простыми предложениями.